# Mercurial - Check sanity patch

Tags: mercurial

I'm using Mercurial and I have a diff thanks to this command : `hg diff`

Here's my diff (example) :

```
diff -r 17899716342e config.js
--- a/config.js Sat Mar 17 14:01:53 2012 +0100
+++ b/config.js Sat Mar 17 18:15:16 2012 +0100
@@ -8,6 +8,6 @@
 ];

 config.hostname = 'localhost';
-config.port = '3000';
+config.port = '8080';

-module.exports = canfig;
+module.exports = config;
```

In another repository, I would like to test is this diff can be applied. I know that `hg import` can import the diff in my current repository.

From the man :

```
-f --force                   skip check for outstanding uncommitted changes
    --no-commit              don't commit, just update the working directory
    --bypass                 apply patch without touching the working
                             directory
```

But there's no argument to just check if the patch can be applied **without modify my repository (and my working tree)**.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest making a local throw-away clone and apply the patch to it if you don't want to modify your current working directory or repository.  I don't think there is a way to do it otherwise.

With extensions you could shelve current changes, apply patch, update clean back to original parent, unshelve changes.  Cloning seems simpler.

Comment: You can also consider using the [Share](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShareExtension) to help make the local clone even cheaper to create.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the (very few) advantages of 'share'.  With hardlinks on your system you're saving neither space nor time over a local clone.  https://gist.github.com/2089965

Answer (score 0):

I like @Mark Tolonen's answer the most -- in Mercurial a new local clone is nearly instantaneous and takes up almost no space due to the use of hard links.

However, if you just can't abide doing so then use the --no-commit option and then revert.

1. `hg import --no-commit the.diff` # check if that succeeds or fails
2. `hg revert --all` # undo the attempted import

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is if I already have some changes independantly of my patch in my working tree, I'll loose it :-(

Comment: Yup, then you should make the clone, which is what I'd do anyway.  In general though you shouldn't be doing much of anything w/ uncommitted changes.  Commit early, commit often.  It's easy enough to collapse them later if your project has an all-commits-must-compile requirement.